# Find Rank and Total Number of Items in MySQL/MariaDB

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, dense-rank

I have a sales summary table like:

```
CREATE TABLE `sales_data` (
  `id` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `start_date` date NOT NULL,
  `end_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `store_sales` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`start_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The `id` column is a Product ID and the `store_sales` is the total item sales for the week.

I'm looking to find the Rank of a particular Product ID based on sales **AND** the total count of unique Products sold - not the sum of sales, but the distinct items.

So far I have:

```
SELECT FORMAT(tmp.rank, 0) AS rank, tmp.id, FORMAT(MAX(tmp.row_num), 0) AS total
FROM (
    SELECT 
        sd.id
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(sd.store_sales) DESC) AS rank,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY sd.id) AS row_num
    FROM sales_data sd
    WHERE sd.start_date >= '2017-01-01'
        AND sd.end_date <= '2017-05-15'
    GROUP BY sd.id
) AS tmp
WHERE tmp.id = 9233
LIMIT 1;
```

The issue I believe, is that the `MAX(tmp.row_num)` is limited by the `WHERE` clause in the outer query and simply selects the row number of that single item.

Is there any way to achieve this without running the subquery twice?

**Edit:**
This is what I'm getting for the inner query:

```
rank,id,total
-------------------
1,4920,2
2,4043,3
3,3514,5
4,2425,7
5,4503,11
...
```

Whereas this is what is desired:

```
rank,id,total
-------------------
1,4920,373
2,4043,373
3,3514,373
4,2425,373
5,4503,373
...
```

So my outer query can select `WHERE id = 4043` and I can print that as `Ranked {rank} out of {total}` to give me `Ranked 2 out of 373`.

Comment: Note that (4) following the int is (luckily) almost meaningless

Comment: It was just a typo really. That tmp.id I just typed in as an example, but thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Some sample data along with actual vs. expected output would be very useful.

Comment: Just added some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

I believe DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(sd.id) DESC) will do the trick.

```
SELECT FORMAT(tmp.rank, 0) AS rank, tmp.id, FORMAT(tmp.row_num, 0) AS total
FROM (
    SELECT 
        sd.id
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(sd.store_sales) DESC) AS rank,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(sd.id) DESC) AS row_num
    FROM sales_data sd
    WHERE sd.start_date >= '2017-01-01'
        AND sd.end_date <= '2017-05-15'
    GROUP BY sd.id
) AS tmp
WHERE tmp.id = 92338
LIMIT 1
```

;

Comment: This oddly doesn't seem to work (I thought it would). If I run the inner query alone, I see strange results - the `row_num`  changes from record to record. So rank 1 has a total of 2. Rank 10 has a total of 17 and Rank 366 has a total of 373. They should all have the same total representing the distinct products sold in the timespan.

Comment: Try rank instead of dense rank @deweyox